# Documentum dql for file location

Tags: dql, documentum

Is it possible to write dql query that will list all files with their location something like execute get_path for '06002bd78000616a' but for all files? I cannot find any solution.

Comment: it is possible. show us what you have problem with

Comment: I have to migrate all documents to a new system but I don't have direct access to database, I have access only through dqMan

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this by using Api script

```
%Collection%=readquery,c,SELECT * FROM documents 
#$Loop %Collection%
    %r_object_id% = get,c,%Collection%,r_object_id
    %path%= getpath,c,%r_object_id%
#$EndLoop
```